# Python: How to Read Multiple Strings in csv File to Compare to Another Singular String for Twitch Bot

Tags: python, csv, bots, ini, twitch

I'm trying to create a Twitch bot that can read a chat message and compare the contents of the message to the contents of a csv file kept in memory. The csv will contain 2 categories: the words/phrases to compare (vertical) and the classification of each word (horizontal) and users will be able to control the selected classification for their channel. Essentially, it is a blacklist for chat messages. All of this will be done in Python. So far, I can:

1. Read the chat
2. Ban chatters
3. Delete messages
4. Send messages in chat

How do I read the contents of the csv by their classifications on the x and y and compare them to the contents of the string pulled from chat? If there isn't a way with csv, perhaps an ini with section and property organization would work?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the CSV file that will contain your data?

Comment: Here's a link on Google Drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wWCqAFfReBTGrhFYzw_NHzq1M8BH-Idc/view?usp=sharing